# Robot framework select dropdown bug

Tags: python, windows, automation, robotframework

I have a desktop application that has a dropdown field. I need to select the number which is equal to value came from the database from the dropdown list. My issue is sometimes it can select the value from the list, but sometime it is not selecting, then continuing without error on my tasks.

Here is my source code of Robocorp.

```
                RPA.Windows.Click    name:"Column right"
                RPA.Windows.Click    name:"Column right"
                Send Keys    keys={TAB}
                #Select    name:SOL_ID    ${get_sol_id}            #Changed this line in order to avoid ActionNotPossible exception. 9/12/2023
                Select    name:"SOL_ID"    ${get_sol_id}            
                Sleep    1s
                
                Send Keys    keys={TAB}
                Send Keys    keys=${get_cif}        
                Send Keys    keys={F4}
                RPA.Windows.Click    name:Cancel
```

`Select    name:"SOL_ID"    ${get_sol_id}` is the code that is selecting the number from the list which is equal to value of database result.
Where did i miss something?

Comment: Here is the log if the issue is appeared:
 action.py[204] select -> Can't find 220 in ComboBoxControl or it does not support selection.